# Unique combinations by group

Tags: r, tidyverse, combinations, euclidean-distance

I have the following data frame structured in terms of 3 variables, i.e Location, Latitude, and Longitude within every single group. I would like to calculate the euclidean distance between all unique location combinations within each group. So for instance, based on the data frame below: the euclidean distance between - (A - London and A - Zurich) and (A - Zurich and A - New York) and (A - New York and A - London). And on a similar note (B - New York and B - London).

Then the average of all these unique distance pairs then needs to be calculated.

```
euc_dist <- function(x1, x2){
 return(sqrt(sum((x1 - x2)^2)))
}
```

```
id  Group  Location Latitude  Longitude

1    A     London    1         2
2    A     New York  3         4
3    A     Zurich    5         6
4    B     New York  7         8
5    B     New York  9         10
6    B     London    11        12
```

The output should look like:

```
id  Group  Average Euclidean distance  

1    A      xx       
2    B      xx
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is your expected output for your example?

Comment: If you're looking for combinations, why did you include [tag:euclidean-distance]? I second the request for expected output, this is not clear to me.

Comment: @AndrewGillreath-Brown@r2evans I have updated the question! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `dplyr` solution:

```r
library(dplyr)
data.frame(Group=gl(2, 3, labels = c("A", "B")),
           Latitude=seq(1, 11, 2),
           Longitude=seq(2, 12, 2)) %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarise(mean_dist=mean(dist(cbind(Latitude, Longitude))))
```

(R's `dist` function defaults to calculating Euclidean distance and does it very, very efficiently)

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Group mean_dist
  <fct>     <dbl>
1 A          3.77
2 B          3.77
```

I'm not totally clear on what the "unique locations" means because each location should only have a single latitude and longitude, correct?